# Java: how to specific "forEach" action type

Tags: java, android

This is my test code, i use intellij idea:

```
package ro.ex;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

class Ex {
    static class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList {
        public MyArrayList(Collection c) {
            super(c);
        }

        @Override
        public void forEach(Consumer action) {
            super.forEach(action);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        MyArrayList<String> a = new MyArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("arg", "arg2"));
        for (String e : a) {

        }
    }

}
```

and idea raise "Error:(23, 25) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.String"

i also try ArrayList

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("arg", "arg2"));
    for (String e : a) {

    }
}
```

everything work well.

**my question is:**

How to make former code pass idea syntax checker?

Comment: Changing the behavior of `forEach` and to a minor degree extending a collection class in the first place looks like a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the generic type argument rather than a [raw type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) for the `ArrayList` to implement type checking

```
static class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList {
```

Should be:

```
static class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
```